# Correct way to detect that a Form had been Dispose()ed

Tags: c#, winforms

If you run the following code then close the form you get a ObjectDisposedException "Cannot access a disposed object." despite the guard clause in the commented line (26).

What is a correct way to detect that a Form has been Dispose()d to prevent this exception from happening?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DisposeExample
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            var handleCreated = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            Form form = null;
            ThreadStart createForm = () =>
            {
                form = new Form();
                form.Show();
                handleCreated.Set();
                Application.Run(form);
            };

            ThreadStart updateData = () =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    if (!form.IsDisposed) // this doesn't prevent ObjectDisposedException
//                        if (form.Visible) // this doesn't prevent ObjectDisposedException
                        form.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => form.Text = form.Text == "A" ? "B" : "A"));
                }
            };
            var updateDataThread = new Thread(updateData);
            updateDataThread.IsBackground = true;

            new Thread(createForm).Start();
            handleCreated.WaitOne();
            updateDataThread.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sayse That makes no sense. The fact that there is no `NullReferenceException` here should already tell you that `form` *isn't* `null`.

Comment: @hvd - it appears I misunderstood, I believed that the form being disposed meant that the form was removed from memory

Comment: It is an unsolvable threading race, you *must* ensure that the form cannot close until you know that the thread has exited.  The programming style is very troublesome, displaying UI on a thread in the MTA can cause *lots* of misery, but a Q&D fix is Environment.Exit() in an event handler for the form's FormClosing event.

Answer (score 3):

If you're disposing the object in a different thread, without any cross-thread synchonisation, there is simply no way. Think about it: if `form.IsDisposed` returns `false`, that different thread may then call `form.Dispose()` before you start your `form.Invoke`, or during.

You cannot reliably prevent `ObjectDisposedException` from being thrown, so just catch the exception and handle it.